# Chat head like facebook messenger with edit text but edit text is not showing keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml

I have implemented chat head kind of pop up for my application using service. And I have used edit text inside that.

But problem is that when I click on edit text only cursor is visible and keyboard is not coming up. And not even able to select or copy paste the text inside that edit text. Any help? Thanks And here is my code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.transition.AutoTransition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotePopUpHead extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mFloatingView;
    EditText editText;


    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    public NotePopUpHead() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
        //Inflate the floating view layout we created
        mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bubble, null);
         editText = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.Email1);

        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LAYOUT_FLAG,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LAYOUT_FLAG,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        }
        
//        Specify the view position
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);


        //Set the close button
        ImageView closeButtonCollapsed = (ImageView) mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
        closeButtonCollapsed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //close the service and remove the from from the window
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        //remember the initial position.
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;

                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        int Xdiff = (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        int Ydiff = (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //The check for Xdiff <10 && YDiff< 10 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                        //So that is click event.
                        if (Xdiff < 10 && Ydiff < 10) {
                            ImageView imageView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.show_more);
                            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    CardView cardView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view);
                                    LinearLayout linearLayout = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.expanded);
                                    if(linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView,
                                                new AutoTransition());
                                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                    } else{

                                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView,
                                                new AutoTransition());
                                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
  


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mFloatingView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView);
    }

    private void startMyOwnForeground() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
            String channelName = "My Background Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)

                    .build();

            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because of the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag which literary says this overlay is not going to get focus under any circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding inside your `EditText` `onClick` method:

```
InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(targetEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Might be good to call `requestFocus()` on the `EditText` as well.

To hide the keyboard:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Required imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
```